# VBA - What is the purpose of the `With` statement

Tags: vba, with-statement

I read the With-Statement documentation from Microsoft and still don't understand  what the purpose of the `With` statement is...

---

[Xpost from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/i9dvzl/when_and_why_use_with_statement), thought this should really be somewhere on Stack Overflow and couldn't find any questions of this nature.

Comment: Personally feel this should be re-opened as it can be answered with facts and citations... `With` doesn't just have a aesthetic benefit. This is the kind of information that should be in the documentation, but isn't.

Comment: Sure, but there is no _do_ or _don't_ here. Some use `With .. End With` always, some sometimes (like me), some never. It's a matter of preference, code style, and habit.

Comment: @Gustav Hmm... I suppose because the performance difference is so negligible in this case I suppose you are correct. Thanks for reviewing :)

Comment: @Gustav: True, but I agree with the OP that an answer which objectively describes the pros and cons of using `With` would be a good fit for SO. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Heinzi, if such description should exist, it would be included in the documentation. To be honest, I am convinced there isn't anything else in this than an option for slightly faster coding in some scenarios. You won't find it, for example, in _C#_ because of the better IntelliSense here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Introduction to `With`

Imagine the following code (Example A):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Font.Color  = rgb(255,0,0)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Font.Bold   = true
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Font.Italic = true
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Font.Size   = 16
```

If we count the `.`s, in this example there are 13. This means that objects are accessed via a property accessor, 13 times in our code.

What happens when we use a `With` statement instead? (Example B):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Font
    .Color  = rgb(255,0,0)
    .Bold   = true
    .Italic = true
    .Size   = 16
End With
```

If we count the `.`s in the new code, we see property accessors are only called 7 times! So we just halfed the amount of work that VBA had to do by using a `With` statement!

This is the primary benefit of using the `With` statement.

### How it works internally

Internally VBA is doing something like this (Example C):

```
Dim temp1 as Object
set temp1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Font
temp1.Color  = rgb(255,0,0)
temp1.Bold   = true
temp1.Italic = true
temp1.Size   = 16
set temp1 = nothing 'More specifically temp1 now calls IUnknown::release()
```

So you can actually imitate the behaviour of `With` with this code, but `With` uses "hidden variables" which don't pollute your local variable scope, so this may be preferred.

---

### Performance Caveats

In regards to performance, the `With` statement can be used in such a way that it has a performance detriment instead of a performance benefit.

#### 1. `A` is a local variable

```
Dim A as SomeObject
set A = new SomeObject
With A
    .B = 1
    .C = 2
    .D = 3
End With
```

In this case A is a local variable. If we run through our conversion:

```
Dim A as SomeObject
set A = new SomeObject
Dim temp1 as SomeObject  'Unnecessary call
set temp1 = A            'Unnecessary call
temp1.B = 1
temp1.C = 2
temp1.D = 3
set temp1 = nothing
```

We see there is potentially some performance detriment in our code, because temp1 needs to be defined and set. The performance decrease will be relatively negligible compared to the property accessors though, so it's unlikely to be noticable. Note that the performance decrease is largely negligible because setting an object doesn't transfer the whole object, but transfer a pointer to the object, which is extremely performant.

**PS:** This performance degradation is just hypothetical at the moment, I'll confirm whether this is true or whether the performance is optimised away by the compiler.

#### 2. `A` is a MEMBER variable

If we have a class with the following code:

```
Public A as object

Sub Test
    With A
        .B = 1
        .C = 2
        .D = 3
    End With
End Sub
```

In this case A is a member/property variable. So actually some information is hidden. Let's correct that:

```
Public A as object

Sub Test
    With Me.A
        .B = 1
        .C = 2
        .D = 3
    End With
End Sub
```

Ah, now we can see that by using `With` we are essentially saving 3 member accessor calls:

```
Dim Temp1 as object
set Temp1 = Me.A
Temp1.B = 1
Temp1.C = 2
Temp1.D = 3
set temp1 = nothing
```

vs

```
Me.A.B = 1
Me.A.C = 2
Me.A.D = 3
```

---

Ultimately what I'm saying is VBA may be using hidden variables that you can't see and thus what's really going on under the hood is very context specific. What you are doing may warrant the usage of `With` in some cases and others not. If in doubt, use `With` because the performance benefits of getting it wrong far outweigh the performance detriments otherwise.

Note: There are a few small benefits to the `With` statement regarding speed of writing code and representation of hierarchy, however these are mainly my personal opinion and do not belong here.

---

### P-Code and Performance Measurements

In case interested, here are some dumps of the PCode for a set of examples with and without the `With` Statement

[image: 1 P-Code Data]

Of course the P-Code is only half the story as different P-Code operations will each have different speeds. Here's a comparison.

[image: 2. P-Code Timings]

The first 3 columns display a test with the 3 cases described at the beginning of this post. The rest of the tests are relatively random but here's what I learnt:

- Local Variables in a with statement appear to be much faster than accessing Member variables.
- Using with has performance penalties for small number of calls.
- As expected `With A.O.O` performs signficantly better than `A.O.O.Prop=...`
- With actually has noticable speed difference. Therefore if you can try to keep your `With` statements outside of any loops you have!

**Note**: all tests ran on Mac version of VBA in Excel 2011

**Note**: All tests run over 10^8 iterations - this means these performance differences, although there, are tiny!!

Comment: That's a SUPER Excelent answer! The way you explained the inner working of vba so simply is astonishing, more of that plz, aligato gosaimasu senpai

Comment: This answer is backwards, really. The readability of `With` is its main feature, and so is the fact that it releases the variable at `End With`, which is [important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20718181/11683). Performance degradation due to *copying one pointer-sized integer* is undetectably negligible, as *copying pointer-sized integers* is about the fastest things processors can do. On contrary, that copying saves much more significant time in most cases, because otherwise that `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Font` will be resolved from scratch each time, starting at `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @GSerg by it "releases" the variable at `End With` do you mean it releases the object from memory? Because that is certainly not the case in reality. `Dim o as Class1: o.a =1: With o: End With: Debug.Print o.a` Will still print 1. Thus `End With` definitely doesn't release the variable. It might indeed release the temporary variable though.

Comment: Yes, it sets the temporary variable to nothing.

Comment: @GSerg That's a good shout, I've added that as a comment to each example I use `temp1`. Of course you wouldn't really be able to access that variable even if you wanted too in the case of `With` statements, but it's good to be complete. I guess I wouldn't know whether the readability of `With` was why it was added, or if it was due to performance. I guess with `With` you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: The first part of this answer is very good, but I really wish you hadn't added that "Performance Caveats" part. Firstly, it's pure speculation (Are you sure that the P-code compiler won't optimize it away? Did you measure it to ensure that the difference is even detectable?), and, secondly, it will cause beginner programmer to make their code even more unreadable by adding even more utterly useless micro-optimizations.

Comment: @Heinzi It is a fair point that I should check the bytecode just to ensure it isn't optimised away. I did mention that it's negligible, especially compared to property access, but I will confirm and rectify the statement :)

Comment: You also write: *"Ultimately what I'm saying is if you are really keen on perforamnce With should only be used when a performance benefit is achieved, ..."*. Everyone considers themselves really keen on performance, but *not* everyone should base their decision whether or not to use With on these micro-optimizations (in fact, almost no-one should). The handful of people who write such highly-optimized VBA code that this difference really matters know half of the VBA spec by heart and don't need SO to tell them what the With statement does.

Comment: @Heinzi reworded the closing statement, hopefully this is better.

Comment: @Heinzi FYI I can confirm that at least the PCode produced by VBA, will cause a performance detriment on 1st pass. The [pCode](https://imgur.com/CFATPfY) has `Dim VarDefn SetStmt New Class1 Set X StartWithExpr Ld X With` where as in the case of the member variable we start immediately with `StartWithExpr Ld A With`. The exec codes, produced after 1st pass, might be different, but this would at least produce a performance decrease on the 1st run of the VBA code.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.